# Enable TextBox inside ListBoxItem after MouseDoubleClick

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox, listbox

I have a TextBox inside a ListBoxItem which is disabled so I can drag and drop it in the ListBox.

Now once I double click it I want it to be Enabled so I can edit the text and when I'm done I want it do be disabled again to do drag and drop.

I have the MouseDoubleClick event on the ListBoxItem but I can't get access to the TextBox. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this.

at the moment textBox is not recognized in codebehind. seems like I don't get access to it the way I'm trying it.

XAML

```
<ListBox Name="Locations"  Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="351" Margin="10,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
     dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteLocationCommand}" />
            </ListBox.InputBindings>

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="ListBoxItem_LostFocus"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Name="textBox" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="270" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="2"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

In View

```
private void ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = sender as ListBoxItem;
        textBox.IsReadOnly = false;
        Locations.textBox.Background = Brushes.White;
        textBox.SelectAll();
        Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
    }

private void ListBoxItem_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          textBox.IsReadOnly = true;
    }
```

Comment: Could you enable it in the `OnDrop` event by using `ListBoxItem`'s `GetVisualChild()`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ReadOnly property which will prevent the user from making any changes to the text:

```
texBox.ReadOnly = true;
```

and

```
private void changeText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).ReadOnly = false;
}
```